# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel plugin delay on page load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jcarousel

Not sure why the plugin is behaving this way but whenever I refresh the page with the carousel plugin, the containing div is blank for like 5-seconds then the carousel will begin to function normally--sliding through.

I created a slimmed down version just to see if there were other things getting in the way of things.  Here's what I have:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/carousel.css" type="text/css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#myJumbotron').carousel();
            }); 

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- JUMBOTRON
===================================================================== -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <section class="span16">

                    <div id="myJumbotron" class="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">

                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="images/jumbotron.jpg" alt="Featured specials" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/940x380" alt="Featured specials" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="images/jumbotron.jpg" alt="Featured specials" />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myJumbotron" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myJumbotron" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
                    </div>

                </section>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

I used the SimpLESS tool to only compile the carousel.less file to its own carousel.css file and the bootstrap.min.css is unmodified as well.

You can see what's happening when going here: [furnitureroadshow.com](http://furnitureroadshow.com).  Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

add for the first item class "active" in html, now you are waiting for 1 cycle .

EX:

```
                       <div class="item active">
                            <img src="images/jumbotron.jpg" alt="Featured specials" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/940x380" alt="Featured specials" />
                        </div>
......
```

Comment: Thanx. Things like this get overlooked after 10 hours of coding. LOL.